# How to access controls on a master page dynamically from another user control, if the web application has nested master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control, say control 1, that looks for control2, which is placed on the root master page : Site.Master

And this is how I am getting Control2 from Control 1 now,

```
    MasterPage showMaster = this.Page.Master.Master;
    MasterPage siteMaster = showMaster.Master;

    Control2= siteMaster.FindControl("Control2");
```

The above code works fine. But because our application uses nested master pages, I am running into a bit of situation here.

How do I find control 2 dynamically regardless of where I put Control1 in which template? Becasue right now, depends on where I put Control1, and how nested is that template in relation to the Site.Master, I have to change how far up in the chain I get Site.Master in the Control 1 code.

Any good ideas on how I can avoid doing that?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a work around with recursively loading the control